# how to store isset condition php to avoid repetition

Tags: php

my code:

```
if (isset($dayMarks[$res['resId']][$dDate])) {
     $var=$dayMarks[$res['resId']][$dDate];
     echo $var;
}
```

note that the isset condition is identical to the value assigned to $var, which creates a pretty ugly code.

How is it possible to assign the condition to $var without repeating it?

(in javascript, I'd write `if (var=$dayMarks[$re...)`  )

Comment: isset checks if key exists to avoid undefined index notices, your code is good, just assign the array value to the variable and then use the variable instead of referencing array.

Comment: Eventually, you'll be able to use the new `??` Null coalesce Ternary operator (https://wiki.php.net/rfc/isset_ternary) in PHP 7...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a common problem in PHP where including files can create uncertainty about variables.

There are a two approaches that work well for me.

**Default Assignment**

With default assignment the $var variable will be given a default value when the key doesn't exist.

> $var = isset($dayMarks[$res['resId']][$dDate]) ? $dayMarks[$res['resId']][$dDate] : false;

After this code can assume that $var will always contain a valid value.

**Default Merger**

My preferred method is to always declare a default array that contains all the required values, and their defaults. Using the False value to mark any keys that might be missing a value (assuming that key holds another value type besides boolean).

```
$default = array(
    'date'=>false,
    'name'=>'John Doe'
);

$dayMarks[$res['resId']] = array_merge($default, $dayMarks[$res['resId']]);
```

This will ensure that the required keys for that variable exist, and hold at least a default value.

You can now test if the date exists.

```
if($dayMarks[$res['resId']]['date'] !== false)
{
     // has a date value
}
```

While this might not work exactly for your array. Since it looks like it's a table structure. There is a benefit to switching to named key/value pairs. As this allows you to easily assign default values to that array.

**EDIT:**

The actual question was if it was possible to reproduce the JavaScript code.

> if (var=$dayMarks[$re...)

Yes, this can be done by using a helper function.

*NOTE:* This trick should only be used on non-boolean types.

```
 function _isset($arr,$key)
 {
    return isset($arr[$key]) ? $arr[$key] : false;
 }

 $a = array('zzzz'=>'hello');
 if(($b = _isset($a,'test')) !== false)
 {
    echo $b;
 }
 if(($c = _isset($a,'zzzz')) !== false)
 {
    echo $c;
 }
```

[See above code here](http://codepad.org/61RzvAft)

Answer (score 0):

```
$isset = isset(...); //save the value
if ($isset) { .... }; // reuse the value
...
if ($isset) { ... }; // reuse it yet again
```

Comment: this will give me a true/false, while what I'm looking for is a way to use the value of the isset condition (e.g $dayMarks[$res['resId']][$dDate]="duck")

Comment: then `$isset = isset($var) ? $var : null;` but now you'ev just added an extra layer... "did I get duck last time, or the default value"?

Answer (score 0):

The only thing you can do is store `$res['resId'][$dDate]`.

```
$var = $res['resId'][$dDate];
if( isset($dayMarks[$var]) ) {
    $var = $dayMarks[$var];
    echo $var;
}
```

Comment: I'm not the downvoter but I guess the problem is, this code won't work if !isset($res['resId'][$dDate]) - in that case it'll break on the first row

Comment: @Roy Of course, but i'm assuming that it exists, like your code. You question was about how to avoid repeted code right?

Comment: Actually no, my problem is that I want to access the value of a var that isn't necessarily defined - first check if it's defined, and only then use it. I think I haven't explained myself good enough, maybe you could help by editting my question as my english is not so good..

Answer (score -1):

If you only want to assign a variable processing simply, you can also write this as:

```
$var = $dayMarks[$res['resId']][$dDate]);
if (!isset($var)) unset($var);
```